# Wrap div around hyperlink (a tag)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a text with multiple links in it. One single link looks like

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/files/test1.pdf" target="_blank">My link</a>
```

First, I would like to wrap `div` tag around all `href` tags but only if `href` is beggining with `http://www.mydomain.com/files/`. So the link above (because it starts with that prefix) should become

```
<div class="myLink">
   <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/files/test1.pdf" target="_blank">My link</a>
</div>
```

Then depending on **file extension** (ending characters of the `href`) add an image before a link so it becomes

```
<div class="myLink">
   <img src="pdf_file_icon.png" alt="File type icon" />
   <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/files/test1.pdf" target="_blank">My link</a>
</div>
```

And optionally add some my text after the link so the final version becomes

```
<div class="myLink">
   <img src="pdf_file_icon.png" alt="File type icon" />
   <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/files/test1.pdf" target="_blank">My link</a>
   <span class="fileSize">1.3 Mb</span>
</div>
```

I need solution for **both PHP** and **JavaScript/jQuery** *(I think it's easier for jQuery because of it's selector capabilites?)*.

---

What I want to get is to move from regular [text link](http://www.google.com) to something like this (don't bother with file size, it's pre-calculated so it's just like any other regular/dummy text)

[image]

### Edit #1

Here is my try in **PHP**

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)(http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/files\/[^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
$text = preg_replace("/$regexp/siU", "<div class=\"fileAttachment\"><img src=\"pdf_file_icon.png\" alt=\"File type icon\" /><a href=\"$2\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a></div>", $text);
```

But I'm not sure how immediately to check for file extension and depending on it insert appropriate image (pdf_file_icon.png)?

Comment: Have you tried anything or would you like us to write your whole app for you?

Comment: Show us the code you got so far and tell as with what exactly are you struggling?

Comment: Updated the first post. I'm struggling with file extension and proper image insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm a bit bored, here's a jQuery implementation:

```
$('a[href^="http://www.mydomain.com/files"]')
    .each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var ext = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        t.wrap('<div class="mylink"></div>');
        switch (ext) {
            case 'pdf': 
               t.before('<img src="pdf_file_icon.png" alt="File type icon" />'); 
               break;
            // Add more types here
        }
        t.after('<span class="fileSize">1.3 Mb</span>');
    }
);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AK9nG/

Surely to do it in PHP you can just edit the HTML directly?

Comment: I need PHP for single rendering when post (text) is created/updated and it's inserted into database and JavaScript for live preview when editing a post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php solution. You'll have to do filesize thingies yourself. Easy to add.

The reason why I don't use preg replace is because this keeps it readable, and unless you're translating > 100kb text files this is fast enough, and makes it for easy debugging.

```
$rawhtml = 'your html file here<a href="http://www.go.com">test</a> and <a href="http://www.do.com/where.pdf">test</a>';
// Explode at every <a tag
$explodedhtml = explode("<a ",$rawhtml);
// Loop through everything
foreach($explodedhtml as $piece)
    {
    // Does our piece contain href?
    if(strpos($piece,"href=") !== false)
        {
            // Extract the url
        $href = substr($piece,strpos($piece,'href=')+6,((strpos($piece,'"',7))-(strpos($piece,'href=')+6)));
        // easy debug
        //echo $href . "<BR>";
            // Does it end in pdf?
        if(substr($href,strlen($href)-4,strlen($href)) === ".pdf")
            {
                    // add all the stuff we want for a pdf file
            $filezie = filsizecomputingfunction();// Put here your filesize thingymejig
            $piece = implode("</a>$filesize</div>",explode("</a>",$piece));// Add filesize here
            $pieces[] =  '<div class="myLink"><img src="pdf_file_icon.png" alt="File type icon" /><a '.$piece;
            }
            // It isn't a pdf...
        else
            {
                    //Just add our closing divs... after the closing tag
            $piece = implode("</a></div>",explode("</a>",$piece));
                    // add to array, add div class and our opening tag
            $pieces[] =  '<div class="myLink"><a '.$piece;          
            }
        }
    // Nothing to detect, just shove it in our array.
    else
        {
        $pieces[] = $piece;
        }
    }
Return to our basic variable so we can work with it in the displaying thingymejig.
$rawhtml = implode('',$pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have the file icon as background image in the  element itself, then using css to apply styles depending on the file-extension:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  background: lighblue url('pdf-icon.png') no-repeat;
  /* etc... */
}
```